# application:openURL:options: not called after deeplink

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, deep-linking, deeplink

Simple scenario. I have an app with URL schemes setup.
e.g.

infoplist contains an Array URL types

That array contains a dictionary with 2 keys: URL identifier (String) and URL Schemes (Array)

Identifier is equal to the bundle id by setting it to $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER).

URL Schemes only contains 1 value "deeplink-test" in this case. In my AppDelegate I have the application:openURL:options: method implemented that returns true.

Now when I go to Safari (on the simulator or device) and type "deeplink-test://" Safari asks me if I want to open the app. I select yes but the deeplink is not called. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is returning true as well. Any idea why the openURL delegate method is not being called? This used to work some time ago but recently I noticed our deeplinks we're not being handled correctly anymore. So the app will open, but the delegate method is not called.

I created a new project with the same implementation where it does work. Is there maybe a Pod that I'm using that is causing the problems?

Pods:

`pod 'Apollo'
pod 'ReactiveObjC'
pod 'Underscore.m'
pod 'Masonry'
pod 'Locksmith'
pod 'INTULocationManager'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
pod 'GoogleTagManager'
pod 'GoogleAppIndexing'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'HockeySDK'
pod 'Adjust'
pod 'UIDevice-Hardware'
pod 'Accengage-iOS-SDK'
pod 'MultiDelegate'
pod 'SwipeView'
pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'PINCache'
pod 'FCFileManager'
pod 'SnapKit'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'RSKGrowingTextView'
pod 'FlexiblePageControl'
pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'React', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
            'Core',
            'RCTText',
            'RCTNetwork',
            'RCTWebSocket',
            'RCTLinkingIOS',
            'RCTImage',
            'RCTAnimation',
            'RCTActionSheet'
        ]
        pod 'Yoga', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
        pod 'CodePush', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-code-push'
        pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
        pod 'react-native-cookies', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-cookies'
        pod 'react-native-navigation', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-navigation'
        pod 'react-native-video', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native-video'`

*EDIT* - added plist source code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>deeplink-test-again</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME} ${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME_SUFFIX}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>11.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>105</string>
    <key>Fabric</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIKey</key>
        <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
        <key>Kits</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>KitInfo</key>
                <dict/>
                <key>KitName</key>
                <string>Crashlytics</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Icon files (iOS 6)</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>icon.png</string>
                <string>icon@2x.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>comgooglemaps</string>
        <string>bma4sreceiver</string>
        <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>xx.xxx.xxx</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>xx.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>`

Comment: Rather than the list of pods, your info plist might be more useful.

Comment: Also, you might try creating a minimal test app that registers a custom URL handler and see if that works for you. That will rule out any pod conflicts or device issues.

Comment: @picciano makes sense. Updated the question and added the plist information as source code. Not sure what you mean with your second comment though. How is testing the deeplink with safari not enough? It seems to open the app so I guess the deeplink is configured correctly. It just doesn't call the openURL delegate method.

Comment: It sounds like your current app (based on the number of pods used) may be large and complex. Reducing the problem of deep linking to a small test app may help you find out what you may have done wrong, while eliminating unrelated issues that may be interfering. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for a better understanding of how to narrow your question to be more effective.

Comment: Right. I was already working a new project to reproduce the problem there. So far I can't. Just wanted to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong in the setup or hoping to find someone who had the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a Pod that I was using for push notifications (https://docs.accengage.com/display/IOS/SDK+Setup). They do something weird during the setup and automatically intercepting the application delegate methods which *should* forward it then to the app.

It doesn't work correctly though.